# Sentence with or without comma

Tags: commas

> The company decided to import it **,** with payment against documents.

It says on the internet that payment against documents is a payment method where the exporter submits the documents to the importer provided that the payment is made for the documents related to the goods sent to the buyer by the exporter.

When I make the sentence above should I use comma before “with”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is optional, but can help to keep the ideas presented clearer. According to the question, "with payment against documents" is a phrase with a specific meaning. With the comma where it is, it helps prevent misunderstandings when there's less context to draw from, or when it's being read by someone who doesn't know the phrase has a special meaning.

For example without the comma it reads:

> The company decided to import it with payment against documents.

A reader might put in their own mental comma, reading it to say:

> The company decided to import it with payment, against documents.

So the comma, though technically optional here, helps keep the technical phrase "with payment against documents" clear.